# by class name counter not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, dom

i create a counter.

```js
dk = parseInt(document.querySelector('.dm').innerText);
for (var i = 0; i <= dk; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector('.dm').innerText = i;
    }, i * 100);
  })(i);
}
console.log(dk);
```

```css
.counter { display: flex; }

.dm {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <div class="dm">40</div>
  <div class="dm">30</div>
</div>
```

problem is only first div counter is working.
can we parse element of innerHTMl by html dom like classname...i try but result is **Nan**.
i want run all counter if i add same classname with different inner values.

Comment: _"i try but result is Nan"_ - There's nothing in the question/snippet that would return `NaN`. Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: Didn't get your question so you want to some up all these dm innerhtml values present inside counter div.
Like for your example 40 + 30 = 70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but if I understood correctly, you want both timer to run simultaneous, right?

If so, then the code below should help.

Use the `querySelectorAll()` to get all elements with same class, then loop through them to get the value and make it increase like you was doing.

```js
const dms = document.querySelectorAll('.dm');

for (let j = 0; j < dms.length; j++){
  let dk = dms[j].innerText;
  
  for(let i = 0; i <= dk; i++){
      setTimeout(function() {   
        dms[j].innerText = i; 
      }, i * 100);
  }
  console.log(dk);  
}
```

```css
.counter{
  display: flex;
}

.dm {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <div class="dm">40</div>
  <div class="dm">30</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you are using [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

When you use `document.querySelector('.dm')` it will return only the first element matching this selector, you need to use `document.querySelectorAll('.dm')` to get all the matching elements.

But with multiple elements you will need a loop to do that, because **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** will return a `nodeList` which is a collection(`array`).

This is how should be your code:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.dm');
Array.from(elements).forEach(function(el, ind){
let dk = parseInt(elements[ind].innerText)
for (var i = 0; i <= dk; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      elements[ind].innerText = i;
    }, i * 100);
  })(i);
}
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.dm');
Array.from(elements).forEach(function(el, ind){
let dk = parseInt(elements[ind].innerText)
for (var i = 0; i <= dk; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      elements[ind].innerText = i;
    }, i * 100);
  })(i);
}
});
```

```css
.counter { display: flex; }

.dm {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <div class="dm">40</div>
  <div class="dm">30</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A `NodeList` is an _array-like_ collection, hence the existence of `.forEach()` is not guaranteed on all browsers -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: @Andreas Yes you are right, I updated it, we just need to wrap it with `Array.from(elements)` to guarantee that.

Comment: To only run into the same problem -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem with IE only but it's more supported and more safe, but the problem I am trying to point out here, is the use of `querySelectorAll` over `querySelector`.